# Why the Locking Buttons? (Project for blind user)

Tags: raspberry-pi, input, button

I was trying to build this: http://www.shaungehring.com/2013/01/03/raspberry-pi-project-1-pandora-streamer/ for a blind user. The large buttons are a key aspect for this target user. But, I've noticed it has [locking buttons listed in the supply](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9808) instead of the momentary switches I would've expected. Would someone be so kind as to tell me why? Unless the design keeps them from locking.

Also, if anyone knows any similar tutorials for making it a C.D. music player, please let me know.

I love learning to program new things, but I'm in a little hurry on this one, so I'm more than willing to follow instructions.

*Note: I initially asked this question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/why-the-locking-buttons-project-for-blind-user, but figured this site was more appropriate.*

Comment: Cross-posting on multiple sites is considered inappropriate. Please remove your question there.

Answer (score 1):

[Locking button](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9808) remains depresses.  This gives a blind person an ability to sense by touch, if some feature (which, perhaps, doesn't manifest itself by sound) is on or off.  Alarm clock would be an example of such feature.  If it were a momentary button, then it would feel the same whether the feature is on or off.

Lever switches, rocker switches, etc is another way of allowing the blind user to sense by touch if something is on or off.

Comment: True, that's a good idea... but for the volume control, sir?  Or should I take the list less literally....

Comment: Procure both types of buttons. Improvise.

Comment: Right.... good thing I already know how to program...